# Append() Python wiping list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to create a list (it'll eventually be a new column in a new df) that contains an edited url if another column contains its. But I'm struggling to get the .append() to stop rewriting the list.

Here is my current code.

```
lst = []

def find_url(i):
    if i == 'mark:':
        doi_index = df["col_d"].index(i)
        code_index = doi_index + 1
        doi_code = df["col_d"][code_index]
        url = 'doi.org/' + doi_code

        lst.append(url)
    else:
        lst.append(0)

for i in df["col_d"]:
    find_url(i)
    
    
print(list)
```

This displays:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

The values in col d are lists, I needed to work out which index stored the value 'mark' so I could find the 'url' in the index after it.

Col_d looks a bit like this:

```
[abc, abc, abc, abc, abc, mark, url]
[abc, abc, abc, abc, abc, mark, url, abc]
[abc, abc, abc, abc, mark, url]
[abc, abc, abc, abc, abc, mark, url, abc, abc, abc]
[abc, abc, url]
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm fairly new to python, so I'm sure it is something obvious. I'd also welcome any critique on how to refactor this.

Comment: Maybe This is due to the fact that You are assigning values to a predefined a pre-defined function `list()` so instead of `list = []` use any variable i.e `lst=[]`

Comment: Can you post more of the code involving the dataframe and URL creation?  Python functions pass by "object reference", so what might be happening is you are putting the same object on the list over and over and at the end something sets it to 0 by accident.

Comment: maybe you shall try : `if 'mark' in i` although due to lack of clarity in question it is hard to say what you are facing

Comment: If you can post a [mre], someone will probably be able to answer you. If you cannot, probably not.

Comment: I have now included the code that I previously left out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you actually using a variable called list? List is an in-built type. It's not a particularly good idea to overwrite that... So I would rename the variable 'list' to something else...

You also seem to be using that 'list' as a global variable. That's not particularly sensible.

You be better to have the function return the result to the for loop.

```
lst = []

def find_url(i):
    if i == 'mark:':
        doi_index = df["col_d"].index(i)
        code_index = doi_index + 1
        doi_code = df["col_d"][code_index]
        url = 'doi.org/' + doi_code
        print('result = %s' % url)
        result = url
     else:
        print('result = 0')
        result = 0
     return result

for i in df["col_d"]:
    lst.append(find_url(i))


print(list)
```

Ah, you've added more about what `df['col_d']` is. It looks like the variable i is going to be a list.

So the function `find_url` will be passed:

```
i = [abc, abc, abc, abc, abc, mark, url]
```

then

```
i = [abc, abc, abc, abc, abc, mark, url, abc]
```

etc.

So

```
i == 'mark:'
```

is never going to be true because a string will never equal a list of things.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the variable name to list as I wrote it in stackoverflow, it was named something else beforehand, so no list/lst has no effect.

Comment: Thank you for the suggested code, unfortunately it returns the same output.

Comment: Then your code is probably is only hitting the 'else' block of the if statement. Put in some print statements to see what is happening.

Comment: I've added where you could put in the print statements to see if you 'if' statement is really working....

Comment: Thanks, I had those print statements in a while ago, and the removed them as they were working. But I can see they don't now, which is probably because I've edited the code too much.

Comment: You're correct with the i = list. I need to nest this if statement a bit further in..

Comment: Cool! If my answer helped you solve the bug, please mark my answer as the accepted one. I guess I get some stack points for that :-) lol